# Fastest possible way of generating n sublists (each of arbitrary size) of an original list without generating the entire power set?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, subset, sage

I feel like this question must have been asked before, but I could not quite find what I am looking for. I have a python list `S` of `100` unique integers each at the magnitude of `10^100`. I want the fastest way to sample `n` elements out of it's power set. In other words, I want `n` unique sublists each of arbitrary length. This can be done by generating `2^n` subsets and picking from them but that is not feasible and very slow. I have tried things like this in a loop,

```py
S[np.random.choice(S.shape[0], np.random.randint(S.shape[0]), replace=False)]
```

But, this is slow and has collisions. Another thing I have tried is using [SageMath's Subsets.random_element()](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/subset.html#sage.combinat.subset.SubMultiset_s.random_element) in a loop. This is better at sampling without collisions but the loop makes it slow.

So, what is the fastest way possible in python to get `n` samples out of the power set (power list?) of a list of unique integers.

This is the bottleneck to the problem I am trying to solve, any library or technique that can accomplish sampling from a powerset feasibly and fast will improve the overall speed for my solution.

Comment: Full code using `choice` might make things clearer.

Comment: Just stick the line with `choice` in a `range(n)` loop and collect returned values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate n boolean masks:

```
n = 4
masks = np.random.randint(2, size=(n,100), dtype=np.bool)
sets = [*map(lambda x: a[x], masks)] # a.shape=(100)
```

You could check if the masks are unique by doing this:

```
len(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.tostring(), 1, masks)) == n
```

But the probability is so low that I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Is `[*map(lambda x: a[x], masks)]` the same as `[a[x] for x in masks]`?

Comment: Yes, it's just a different way @scribe

Comment: Is there a reason you'd use `np.random.random((n, 100))>p` instead of `np.random.randint(2, size=(n,100), dtype=np.bool)`, I am running out of memory with the former with shape `(10^8, 50)`. I guessed since `np.bool` takes less space, it will do better in terms of memory?

Comment: Maybe that way is even better, I will edit my answer to put that way @scribe